# Accidentally unfollowed a friend on Facebook and want to reverse it

Tags: facebook

When I look at my activity log on Facebook, I see I accidentally unfollowed a good friend.  Now I can’t see comments he’s posted in the upper right hand corner where you see comments your friends have made on other people’s timeline.

How do I reverse this?

Comment: Go to his profiile and follow him again..

Answer (score 6):

Ring him up, and tell him that you accidentally unfollowed him on Facebook, and that to fix this he will need to accept the friend-request you are just about to send.   Apologise for inconveniencing him in this way.

If he's really a friend, then he will be happy to do this.    :-)

Answer (score 0):

Deepak is correct if you are talking about subscriptions and not friend requests.

Go to your friend list or friend's profile hover over the friends button and select show in news feed.

[image: Show in news feed]